# Celery is rerunning long running completed tasks over and over

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I've a python celery-redis queue processing uploads and downloads worth gigs and gigs of data at a time.

Few of the uploads takes upto few hours. However once such a task finishes, I'm witnessing this bizarre celery behaviour that the celery scheduler is rerunning the just concluded task again by sending it again to the worker (I'm running a single worker) And it just happened 2times on the same task!

Can someone help me know why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

The tasks are definitely finishing cleanly with no errors reported just that these are extremely long running tasks.

Comment: Try using [flower](http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to see what's happening in your celery queue.

Comment: I see a bunch of queued tasks but that's about it. Is there anything specific I need to look at?

Comment: @avinash can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @avinash Kindly refrain from posting half-assed "answers" which leads nowhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently ran into this issue, and eventually figured out that tasks were
running multiple times because of a combination of
[task prefetching](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-prefetch-multiplier) and tasks exceeded the
[visibility timeout](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/redis.html#visibility-timeout). Tasks are acknowledged right before they're executed (unless you set ACKS_LATE=True),
and by default 4 tasks are prefetched per process. The first task will be
acknowledged before execution, but if it takes over an hour to execute then the
other prefetched tasks will be delivered to another worker where it will
be executed an additional time (or in your case,
executed an additional time by the same worker).

You can solve by increasing the visibility timeout to something longer than the longest possible runtime of your tasks:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600*10}  # 10 hours
```

You could also set `PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER=1` to disable prefetching so that long running tasks don't keep
other tasks from being acknowledged.

Comment: Actually, the prefetch multiplier can't be disabled unless you are using `acks_late`. If `acks_late` is disabled, the main process still reserves 1 additional task for every worker process (`--concurrency`).

Moreover, it can reserve unlimited scheduled tasks (`celery inspect scheduled`) until it encounters enough tasks to feed its children (`celery inspect active`) and fill the main queue up to the prefetch multiplier (`celery inspect reserved`). See https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6500

Comment: Note that the `visibility_timeout` only applies to the Redis transport. A similar param for RabbitMQ is the [`consumer_timeout`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout)

Comment: @Emilio
Facing the same problem, celery re-running the same tasks over and over again indefinitely. Can you please tell me how to set consumer_timeout as I am using rabitmq.

Comment: Hi @codemastermind, the RabbitMQ official documentation for [`consumer_timeout`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout) explains how to do that. Basically, you should add the `consumer_timeout` parameter to your `rabbitmq.conf` file (and likely restart RabbitMQ or make it reload the config somehow). Notice that this has nothing to do with your Python or Django setup.