# Celery executing task multiple time

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

I have a celery task as follows:

```
@celery_app_site24x7.task(queue='site24x7')
    def createWebsiteMonitoring(**kwargs):
        """ Celery Task to create or update website Moniroting """

        time.sleep(100)
        site24x7Instance = Business_api.thirdpartyFactory.instantiate(
            "site24x7")
        # site24x7Instance.login()
        return site24x7Instance.createWebsiteMonitoring(**kwargs)
```

The issue is that my task is being run by multiple worker Fork POOL:

+++++++

> [2019-01-23 05:40:59,674: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task
>   celery_tasks.site24x7.createWebsiteMonitoring[a6eeff3d-fa01-4f2e-9921-849435c9b902]
>   succeeded in 128.61932249739766s: '279832000003876475'
>
> [2019-01-23 05:49:32,565: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task
>   celery_tasks.site24x7.createWebsiteMonitoring[a6eeff3d-fa01-4f2e-9921-849435c9b902]
>   succeeded in 127.42566008213907s: '279832000003877559'

+++++++

Hence the same task is being run multiple time.

On the other hand am having some errors in the worker logs as follows:

> redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from socket:
>   ('Connection closed by server.',)
>
> [2019-01-23 06:58:01,453: WARNING/MainProcess] Restoring 15
>   unacknowledged message(s)
>
> [2019-01-23 06:58:01,641: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to
>   redis://46.19.177.13:6379/10

Some time:

> [2019-01-23 05:58:19,791: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to
>   broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...

Is there any issue with my code? Why the same task is being run twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Celery is rerunning long running completed tasks over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310899/celery-is-rerunning-long-running-completed-tasks-over-and-over)

Comment: @Kheshav Sewnundun did you find solution to this? Facing the same issue

Comment: Also refer [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4400) github issues thread for possible resolution