# celery re-running the same tasks over and over again indefinitely if there are any issues with rabimq/celery server in Python

Tags: python, django, celery, amqp, django-celery

I have searched about this but did not get an expected answer.

There is the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310899/celery-is-rerunning-long-running-completed-tasks-over-and-over) asked but it applies to redis which can be solved by setting,

`BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 3600*10}  # 10 hours`

I tried this but does not work as I got to know that this applies only to Redis and for rabitmq we have to use `consumer_timeout`. But not sure how can we set it up? or how to use it with rabitmq python/Django setting.

I am using `amqp==2.6.1`, `celery==4.2.2`, `Python 3.8` `Django==3.0.4`.
and CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT configurations,

```
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'max_retries': 3,
    'interval_start': 0,
    'interval_step': 0.5,
    'interval_max': 3,
}
```

Running multiple celery shared_task at a time. In the middle, if the rabbitmq is down or any issues with the server. I can see celery re-running the same tasks over and over again indefinitely.

How to stop this re-running the celery task indefinitely?